# javascript parsing json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a problem with javascript, im calling an ajax method that returns this string:

```
{
  "ObjectResponse": {
    "Operation": "OK",
    "Response": "SUCCESS",
    "Message": "List of AAA Found",
    "List": [
      {
        "keySource": "gat\/images\/images_set\/apple.jpg",
        "idSiteKey": "1",
        "text": "Apple"
      },
      {
        "keySource": "gat\/images\/images_set\/cat.jpg",
        "idSiteKey": "2",
        "text": "Cat"
      },
      {
        "keySource": "gat\/images\/images_set\/coffee.jpg",
        "idSiteKey": "3",
        "text": "Coffee"
      },
      {
        "keySource": "gat\/images\/images_set\/dog.jpg",
        "idSiteKey": "4",
        "text": "Dog"
      },
      {
        "keySource": "gat\/images\/images_set\/horse.jpg",
        "idSiteKey": "5",
        "text": "Horse"
      },
      {
        "keySource": "gat\/images\/images_set\/police.jpg",
        "idSiteKey": "6",
        "text": "Police"
      },
      {
        "keySource": "gat\/images\/images_set\/tree.jpg",
        "idSiteKey": "7",
        "text": "Tree"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I assing the content in this way:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = ensureReadiness; 
....
responseText = xhr.responseText;
```

If i try to parse it on javascript with:

```
response = JSON.parse(responseText);
```

if I acces a property such `response.ObjectResponse.Operation` I do get the right content.. but when I try to access the List it allways brakes

and if I try the same String but instead of calling the service I assign the content to a var it works I do can access the List

```
var myTemporalString ='{"ObjectResponse":{"Operation":"OK","Response":"SUCCESS","Message":"List of Keys Found","List":...';
response.JSON.parse(myTemporalString);
```

Any suggestion why this could be happening?

Comment: This `responseText = xhr.responseText;` shoud be done inside `ensureReadiness`. You can only use the response from there.

Comment: It's definitely not related to the actual XHR response. What happens when you try to access the `.List`? What do you mean by "it breaks"?

Comment: You should probably post more code.

Comment: `List` is an array of object so you should use `List[0]['keySource']` to get the first object and `List[1]['keySource']` for the second and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way,

```
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {

                        try{
                                var mJsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                            }catch(err){
                                console.log(err);
                                alert(err);
                                return;
                            }

                        for(i=0;i<jsondata.ObjectResponse.List.length;i++){
                                   console.log(jsondata.ObjectResponse.List[i].text);
                                 console.log(jsondata.ObjectResponse.List[i].keySource);
                                   console.log(jsondata.ObjectResponse.List[i]. idSiteKey);
                           }

              }
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop!

```
var array = response.ObjectResponse.List;
var len = array.length;
for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
    //Use array[i] to access the list
    array[i].keySource
    array[i].idSiteKey
    array[i].text
}
```